# How to invoke C++ methods with function pointers as arguments from Java (Android)

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, java-native-interface

I need to integrate C++ files into my Android application project.
I can build the files and .so file is generated.

This is the header file which has the function process(). 
I need to invoke this method from my .java file.

```
class PayrollGenerator {

public:
    typedef void (* PAYROLL_READY_CALLBACK) (std::vector<int> list, int id);
    typedef void (* PROGRESS_CALLBACK) (int progress);

private:
    PAYROLL_READY_CALLBACK _dataReadyCallback;
    PROGRESS_CALLBACK _progressCallback;

public:
     DataProcessor(PAYROLL_READY_CALLBACK dataReadyCallback, PROGRESS_CALLBACK progressCallback);
    void process(int data);
};
```

Two callbacks are there which will give me result and the  progress data of the data being processed.
I am not able to design the JNI methods for it.
BTW, I am run simple C++ programs from .java files.
But this one is quite complex to me.
Please help !!

Progress - 
I created a C++ file and wrote the wrapper

```
JNIEnv *global;
jobject impl;

struct DataProcessorStruct {
jobject callback_ptr;
DataProcessor *dataProcessor;
};

void dataReadyCallback(std::vector<jint> processedSamples, jint heartRate){
jintArray arr = global->NewIntArray( processedSamples.size() );
global->SetIntArrayRegion( arr, 0, processedSamples.size(), ( jint * ) &processedSamples[0] );

jclass clazz = global->FindClass("com/app/AudioActivity");
jmethodID method = global->GetMethodID(clazz, "dataReady","[Ljava/util/List;I)V");
global->CallVoidMethod(impl,method,arr,heartRate);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "test", "C-dataReadyCallback");
}

void progressCallback(jint progress){

jclass clazz = global->FindClass("com/app/AudioActivity");
jmethodID method = global->GetMethodID(clazz, "dataProcessProgress","(I)V");
global->CallVoidMethod(impl, method,progress);
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "test", "C-progressCallback");
}

 JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_app_AudioActivity_createDataProcessorObject (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj){
global = env;
impl = obj;

DataProcessorStruct *cpp_obj = new DataProcessorStruct();

if (cpp_obj == NULL) {
    return 0;
}

DataProcessor *csObj = new DataProcessor(dataReadyCallback,progressCallback);
if (csObj == NULL) {
    return 0;
}
cpp_obj->dataProcessor = csObj;
cpp_obj->callback_ptr = env->NewGlobalRef(obj);
return (jlong)cpp_obj;
}


JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_app_processData (JNIEnv * env, jobject obj,jlong objId,jint sample,jint dataLeft){
impl = obj;
DataProcessorStruct *cpp_obj = (DataProcessorStruct *)objId;
DataProcessor *dataProcessor=cpp_obj->dataProcessor;
if (dataProcessor != NULL){
    dataProcessor->process(sample,dataLeft);
}
}
```

The native methods in Java are -

```
public native long createDataProcessorObject();
public native void processData(long dataProcessor,int sample, int dataLeft);
```

Is this the right way of doing so ?
And is there any way I don't have to call class Java methods directly from dataReadyCallback() and progressCallback() C++ methods but somehow I can call interface methods which are in Java to get invoked from these C++ methods so that any class listening to these callbacks should get notified and not a particular class?

Comment: You need to marshal the data between a Java type and a C++ one. Check out [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/).

Comment: I can't use third party software due to company policies.

Comment: SWIG is a tool that generates code to marshal calls between languages, if your company prohibits you from using tools that make you productive your company sucks.

Comment: I tried SWIG but it is not giving any result when I post my C++ code into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily define native functions in Java wich are callbacks in your C++ programme.  Usually you start declaring a class and some functions in java:

```
class MyJNative {
    static {   // static bloc, executed when class is loaded => load your cpp library
        System.out.print ("Load library in ");
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
        System.loadLibrary("MyNativeCPP");
    }

    private static int next_id=1;   // every object gets a unique id
    private int id;                 // unique object id

    public MyJNative () {           // constructor (sets unique id)
        id = next_id++; 
        // ... 
    }

    public native static void doSetup(); // initialisation for your factory function
    public native void doSomething();  // example method 
    ...
}
```

Then you'll let `javah` generate the header for the native funtions in C++. You shouldn't hand-write the header yourself ! Here a step by step [tutorial](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~slonnegr/wpj/JNI.pdf), and the example for the code above:

```
...
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     MyJNative
 * Method:    doSetup
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MyJNative_doSetup
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);

/*
 * Class:     MyJNative
 * Method:    doSomething
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_MyJNative_doSomething
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

...    
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

As you see, JNI is designed to call C++/C functions and not member functions of C++ class. So you need to define some global functions (or static member functions of your class), that will get as a (first) parameter some ID which can identify the C++ object, and will then forward the call to this object.

The example above is simplified, but the idea would be that, the Java class maintains a unique ID.  You could imagine that at creation, after setting the ID, it calls a factory function in C++, that would maintain a `map<jint, unique_ptr<MyCPPclass>> objects` so that all other functions like `doSomething()` can be invoked with ID as parameter and then call `objects[ID].get()->doSomething()`.

The problem with this approach is the life of your C++ object:  you manage it's destruction:  C++ objects created on the C++ side won't be garbage collected, so it's difficult to guess when they are no longer needed.

A variant of this approach would be to host ther you "host it" somewhere in a byte array of a java object. But in this case the problem is the other way round:  when the Java object is no longer needed, the C++ side won't be informed that the object is destructed and so the destructor won't be called.

As you can see, the JNI design makes it rather difficult to manage objects on both sides.  So the safest approach is to manage objects on one side only and on the other side expose only functions that will use/manipulate the object.

Comment: Can you please provide some code for the mentioned problem ?

Comment: I know this but my problem is different. The method which I want to invoke contains callbacks as arguments and that's where I am blocked.

Comment: It's exactly the same principle: the callback pointers are c++ class data. You'll need a native wrapper function that finds/constructs your claa and invoke your member function pointer.